# Get count of a value of a subdocument inside an array with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Collection of documents with id and contact. Contact is an array which contains subdocuments.

[image: image of the document]

I am trying to get the count of contact where isActive = Y. Also need to query the collection based on the id. The entire query can be something like

Select Count(contact.isActive=Y) where _id = '601ad0227b25254647823713'

I am using mongo and mongoose for the first time. Please edit the question if I was not able to explain it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline like this:

- First `$match` to get only documents with desired `_id`.
- Then `$unwind` to get different values inside array.
- Match again to get the values which `isActive` value is `Y`.
- And `$group` adding one for each document that exists (i.e. counting documents with `isActive`= Y). The count is stores in field `total`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"id": 1}
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$contact"
  },
  {
    "$match": {"contact.isActive": "Y"}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "total": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KGhLF9dnZKE)